# Комментарии с начала строки

Tags: phpstorm

Можно ли сделать в PHPStorm, чтобы автоматическое комментирование строки (по хоткею) начиналось не с начала строки, а на том же уровне, что и предыдущая строка?

### [image: пример]

В настройках (Settings => Project => Code Style => PHP => Wrapping and Braces) нашёл такой параметр - "Comment at first column", убрал галку, но не помогает. В PHP и JS файлах комментарий начинается с начала строки.

[Судя](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14262) по всему, это работает только в [8 версии](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/06/new-and-changed-formatting-options-in-phpstorm-8/).

Но, может, есть вариант сделать это в версии 7.1.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу, чтобы закрыть вопрос, а то сразу забыл.

Пошёл по пути наименьшего сопротивления и поставил PHPStorm 8. В целом стало значительно лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Выбрать:

```
Editor->Code Style->PHP->Code Generation
```

и там снять галку:

```
Line Comment at first column
```